# How to write javascript code for two columns text area

Tags: javascript

I have a website where I need to display cryptocurrency live rates with this javascript code

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://files.coinmarketcap.com/static/widget/currency.js"></script>
<div class="coinmarketcap-currency-widget" data-currency="ripple" data-base="USD" data-secondary="" data-ticker="true" data-rank="true" data-marketcap="true" data-volume="true" data-stats="USD" data-statsticker="false"></div>
```

I also have three other JavaScript codes like this for other cryptocurrencies they display on my site like this

[image]

But I need them to display in two columns

Please anyone can help to do this?

Answer (score -1):

There is no need at all to use Javascript.

You can easily achieve this using [Bootstap's Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

Or if you are not using Bootstrap, try this CSS rules, courtesy of [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_two_columns.asp).

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 2%;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://files.coinmarketcap.com/static/widget/currency.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="coinmarketcap-currency-widget" data-currency="ripple" data-base="USD" data-secondary="" data-ticker="true" data-rank="true" data-marketcap="true" data-volume="true" data-stats="USD" data-statsticker="false"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="coinmarketcap-currency-widget" data-currency="bitcoin" data-base="USD" data-secondary="" data-ticker="true" data-rank="true" data-marketcap="true" data-volume="true" data-stats="USD" data-statsticker="false"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```